# Quicksort and Mergesort questions about special cases

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I think I understand with quicksort but i would like confirmation and am a bit confused with the mergesort part.

Suppose we apply Quicksort to n items in **initially sorted order**. Will at least one element be involved in theta(n) comparisons? How about **initially random order**?

Suppose we apply Mergesort to n items in **initially sorted order**. Will at least one element be involved in theta(n) comparisons? How about **initially random order**?

Comment: For the entry level of quick sort, the pivot value will be compared against n-1 other elements. For merge sort the worst case possible number of comparisons with a single element could occur on the final pass, merging a run of size 1 with a run of size n-1, again n-1 comparisons.

Comment: Merge best case: "zipper-like merge": "every" element will be compared to *two* others.

Comment: I doubt that the question about Quicksort ca be answered without knowing the pivot selection rule.

Answer (score -1):

Yes to both, presorted or not.

Think about it: You cannot sort without comparing ***n*** items at least once*, even if only to check that they are in fact already sorted.

*(unless you know *a priori* that some subsequences are already sorted in their final order, which you cannot assume in a general-purpose sort)

...

Unless I’ve misread your question. Are you asking if the *same* element is used in ***n*** comparisons?

Comment: I am afraid your last sentence holds.